# DaggerAppComponent not created

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

With dagger 2.10 I used to be able to create the app component by doing

```
    sAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .sessionModule(new SessionModule())
            .netModule(new NetModule())
            .dataModule(new DataModule())
            .build();
```

I was already using the AndroidInjector for Activities and everything was fine.
Now I switched to 2.11 and I can't find the way to create the app component.
In the [google tutorial](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) I see:

```
DaggerYourApplicationComponent.create()
    .inject(this);
```

to be added in the onCreate of the Application. 
In my case `DaggerYourApplicationComponent = DaggerAppComponent`. The problem is that DaggerAppComponent class isn't created anymore.

I have:

```
public class App extends android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication implements HasActivityInjector {
    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> mDispatchingActivityInjector;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        sAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this); //here the error
```

and:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AppModule.class,
        MainActivityModule.class,
        ...
})
public interface AppComponent {
        void inject(App app);
        ...
}
```

in the build.gradle file I have:

```
def daggerVer = 2.11
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVer"
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVer"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVer"
```

Comment: In the manifest, did you register the application class?

Comment: Yes and the app is working fine with version 2.10

Comment: Instead try `DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this).inject(this)`.

Comment: @azizbekian  DaggerAppComponent does not exist at all

Comment: @kingston This tends to indicate that Dagger failed to generate the file, and has printed the _reason_ for the failure into your compiler output. Can you find that and paste that in here?

Comment: @JeffBowman I see only the class not found error and if I remove the line sAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this); the build succeeds with no warnings but of course the AppComponent instance does not exists.

Comment: I'll try to create a small project to be shared

Answer (score 66, accepted):

With the dependencies listed below everything works:

If you are using Kotlin

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    def daggerVer = 2.27 // or latest version

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVer"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVer"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVer"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVer"
}
```

If you are using Java:

```
dependencies {
    def daggerVer = 2.27 // or latest version

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVer"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVer"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVer"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVer"
}
```

See [google tutorial](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html)

You can find the latest release number [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases).

Comment: Did this and refuses to see it.  clean, cleanBuildCache, nothing is working.

Comment: @JPM are you using kotlin?

Comment: yes using dagger.  Turns out it was due to Inject on fields still showing fields as private.  I added JvmField annotation and that went away then.

Comment: Solved my problem. Use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor` as suggested on Dagger 2 GitHub page.

Comment: Had this thing disturbing me for 24 hours. I'm developing my app in both Kotlin and Java. When I added 'kapt' next to the annotationProcssors counterparts and it worked.

Comment: @Denny you should not need to add both even if you are using java and kotlin. kapt should be enough

Comment: @Denny what do you mean? Which one would you exclude? I have replaced `annotationProcessor` with `kapt`

Comment: After adding above, make sure to have internet permission in manifest file, otherwise it won't generate stub classes

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 10):

In **Kotlin**, we have to add *kapt* compiler plugin to use Dagger 2.

In your app gradle, add this plugin

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

And add dependencies as below

```
dependencies
{
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$latest_version"
    kapt  "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$latest_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$latest_version"
    kapt  "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$latest_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$latest_version"
    kapt  "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.12"
}
```

> See Kotlin
>   [Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html)

Answer (score 3):

in my case (currently using kotlin)

i use this build gradle

```
  implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24'
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24'
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.24'
  implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.24'
```

after sync gradle,

1. I quit Android studio (Command + Q).
2. Delete folder "build" inside 'app' folder
3. reopen Android Studio

DaggerAppComponent created.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Dagger2 only support below settings in Gradle:
https://github.com/google/dagger#gradle

```
def daggerVer = 2.24 // or latest version
api "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVer"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVer"
api "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVer"
api "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVer" // if you use the support libraries
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVer"
```