# Unable to resolve DaggerAppComponent

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2

I have gone through various stackoverflow link some of the link are :

[LInk 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652204/daggerappcomponent-not-created)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755753/cannot-find-symbol-class-daggerappcomponent-or-cannot-find-symbol-class-daggerac?rq=1)

but no one solve this below are the gradle file and my application :

```
    // dependency injection
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.14.1'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.14.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.14.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'
```

And the MyApplication file is :

```
 DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this);

    AppLogger.init();
```

[image]

Comment: It will generated when code compile. i was facing this same issue but after compiling it was generated automatically

Comment: Not generating.

Comment: did you check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251222/error-cannot-find-symbol-variable-daggerappcomponent

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thanxx.

Answer (score 3):

You have to build the project after setting up dagger and then start typing Dagger and Android Studio will show the class it built for dagger component

Comment: You have to setup dagger correctly, double check from those links and after setting up build the project and you will see it, the class will be related to the name of your component class

Comment: Thanxxx for giving your time now i  got it.

Comment: Can you accept the answer so that it might help others in the same scenario

Answer (score 2):

There is many methods to solve it,

Below methods are worldwide problem solver

1. Click on Invalidate/cache restart in android studio
2. Close android studio, Go > androidStudio installed folder and delete cache folder manualy and start again.
3. Rename dagger component and again clean/rebuild your project.

These 3 methods can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I applied the plugin 'kotlin-kapt' in the gradle file, it caused the DaggerAppComponent to not be found. Disabled it and the DaggerAppComponent was found again and I am using Dagger 2.28.1.

So the issue could be linked to specific changes with the plugins.